# Rails 3 gem for capturing referrer info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, rubygems, referrer

Is there a single (or multiple) Rails gem that will help to easily capture the following on a when registering a new model instance (i.e.: new user)?

- referrer URL
- traffic source (google, bing, etc.)
- traffic medium (organic, cpc)
- search terms (if user came from a search engine)

I know I could code this in manually, but no reason to recreate this if it's already done.

The only thing I could find through searching is [search_sniffer](https://github.com/squeejee/search_sniffer), but that's a plugin, and I'd prefer to use a gem if available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving this on my own without a gem.  In case anyone is interested, I wrote a [blog post](http://www.matthuggins.com/articles/tracking-new-user-registrations-by-source-search-terms) explaining how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

[Referrer](https://github.com/salkar/referrer) tracks sources with which users visit your site, converts them into utm markup, computes priority of these sources and provides linking for sources with tracked model's records (orders/requests/etc). Rails 4, 5 supported.